# how did developers share git repos before GitHub?

Tags: linux, git, github, version-control, linux-kernel

How did developers share their local git repositories with others before GitHub(or any web-based hosting service for version control using Git)?

Comment: Here's an [email from Linus](https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/10/1/376) from 2007, between the creation of Git in 2005 and GitHub in 2008, giving people a `git.kernel.org` URL they can clone. This is still how the kernel is developed today (it is not done on GitHub)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was always possible to share a repo using HTTP with a fairly minimal web server setup.  Or you could set up an SSH server.  Or use a shared folder (though you would still want to put a bare repo on the file share, and then make clones for each developer's local).

(You also *could* transfer info back and forth on discs or USB drives, or any other method.  You generally wouldn't share the entire repo this way, though; you would create "bundle" files and share those, and the receiving end would treat the bundle like a remote repo.)

Hosting services like GitHub just build on these transport options that were built into git beforehand; what the services *really* add isn't basic remote access, but rather things like access control, workflow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could always create your very own Git SSH server by setting up the sshd service properly on a Unix like box (creating the git user and appending the different collaborators public keys to the git user .ssh/authorized_keys file etc, further information [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)), and just executing the next command to create the repositories in the Git SSH server

```
git init --bare name_of_repo
```

The Git web based servers like GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket,etc helped a lot to make the user management way easier and also added many other goodies like the projects and organizations administration, repository teams and collaborators, ease of code browsing and reviewing, etc but all of them are on the top of git base